# Equivalent of belongs_to through in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want to do is to  get the equivalent of belongs_to through. My rationale is that I don't want to generate lots of db calls, while traversing my model structure.

My example in pseudo format:

```
Manufacturer
  has_many: machines

Factory
  has_many: machines
  has_many: people

Machine
  belongs_to: manufacturer
  belongs_to: factory

People
  belongs_to: factory
```

I want starting from a Manufacturer record(s), to get all the people in the factory where those manufacturers machines exist.

The only way I can think of is by iterating through manufacturer.machines.each, and calling factory.people (or calling people using a delegate), but I'd love to do it all in one call.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Manufacturer` model you could have these relations:

```
has_many :machines # You probably already have this one
has_many :factories, through: :machines
has_many :people, through: :factories
```

Let's say `bob` is a `Manufacturer`. You can now get all the people in all the factories where `bob`'s machines exist.

```
bob.people
```

*Note that I renamed the `People` model to `Person` when I tested it. You should try to keep your model names singular as much as possible.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm seeming to go fuzzy brained with this, so will need to try it out and get back, if the has_many: factories, through :machines works then I can see it would work

Comment: Ah.. basic fundamental misunderstanding on my part. I believed that you could not use belongs_to as the through relationship. Silly. I'd assumed that it had to be another has_many. I was thinking in terms of collection behaviour and not how an inner join would perform. Many thanks!